# decode UTF-8 charset to its local language in Javascript or other client side. is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml, multilingual

My use case is storing translated data (in this example Ukraine) in Elasticsearch, which natively stores in UTF-8
I want to encode it back to its original language when displayed on the client side.
is it possible? (i have the original expected language and it exist on client side query)

```
"description_uk" : """\u041a\u043e\u043b\u0438 \u043f\u0440\u0435\u043a\u0440\u0430\u0441\u043d\u0438\u0439 \u043d\u0435\u0437\u043d\u0430\u0439\u043e\u043c\u0435\u0446\u044c \u0432\u0435\u0434\u0435 \u043a\u043e\u043c\u043f'\u044e\u0442\u0435\u0440\u043d\u043e\u0433\u043e \u0445\u0430\u043a\u0435\u0440\u0430 \u041d\u0435\u043e \u0434\u043e \u0437\u0430\u0431\u043e\u0440\u043e\u043d\u043d\u043e\u0433\u043e \u043f\u0456\u0434\u0437\u0435\u043c\u043d\u043e\u0433\u043e \u0441\u0432\u0456\u0442\u0443, \u0432\u0456\u043d \u0432\u0438\u044f\u0432\u043b\u044f\u0454 \u0448\u043e\u043a\u0443\u044e\u0447\u0443 \u0456\u0441\u0442\u0438\u043d\u0443 - \u0436\u0438\u0442\u0442\u044f, \u044f\u043a\u0435 \u0432\u0456\u043d \u0437\u043d\u0430\u0454, \u0454 \u0441\u043a\u043b\u0430\u0434\u043d\u0438\u043c \u043e\u0431\u043c\u0430\u043d\u043e\u043c \u0437\u043b\u043e\u0433\u043e \u043a\u0456\u0431\u0435\u0440-\u0456\u043d\u0442\u0435\u043b\u0435\u043a\u0442\u0443.""",
```

Comment: I'm not sure I got your question right; it would be great if you could a more elaborate example :). Just to wrap my head around it - you translated a string from English to Ukrainian, you store it as Ukrainian encoded with UTF-8, and you want to display it back in English on the server-side?

Comment: almost... the Elasticsearch convert it to UTF-8. the sample is what is stored in Elasticsearch now. 
I want to convert it back to Ukraine for display on browser.
(if the data is not lost during put in the storage)

Comment: so, you just want to convert the Ukrainian back?

Comment: yes, exactly. not sure its really doable but that what i'm looking for

Comment: There should be no problem displaying this; it appears in Ukrainian when I log it into my console. But maybe I still don't get you